# Cannot load the image from database to thymleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

This is my editprofile.html:

```
<form th:action="@{/updateProfile}" method="post" class="signin-form" th:object="${editprofile}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="title-main text-center mx-auto mb-md-5 mb-4" style="max-width:500px;">
        <h5 class="footer-title-29">Personal Details</h5>
        <div class="col-sm-6 profile_Pic">
            <img id="thumbnail" th:src="*{'data:image/jpg;base64,'+profile_pic}" width="200" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="input-grids">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name" class="contact-input" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="mobileNumber">Mobile Number:</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{mobileNumber}" id="mobileNumber" class="contact-input" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" id="email"
                                   class="contact-input" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title-main text-center mx-auto mb-md-5 mb-4" style="max-width:500px;">
        <h5 class="footer-title-29">Address Details</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="input-grids">
        <label class="control-label" for="address1">Address Line 1:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{address1}" id="address1" class="contact-input" />
        <label for="address2">Address Line 2:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{address2}" id="address2" class="contact-input" />
        <label class="control-label" for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{city}" id="city" class="contact-input" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="state">State:</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{state}" id="state"
                                   class="contact-input" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="zipCode">Zip Code:</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{zipCode}" id="zipCode"
                                   class="contact-input" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="fileImage">Upload image</label>
                <input type="file" name="fileImage" accept="image/*" id="fileImage" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 login-center text-start">
        <button class="btn btn-style btn-style-3 text-left" >Update</button>
        <a th:href="@{/dashboard}" class="new-user text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-style btn-style-3 text-left" th:formaction="@{/displayProfile}">BACK</button></a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I did a compress and decompress when adding and retrieving the data from db

Code: ImageUtil.java

```
public static byte[] compressImage(byte[] data) {

        Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
        deflater.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
        deflater.setInput(data);
        deflater.finish();

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

        while (!deflater.finished()) {
            int size = deflater.deflate(tmp);
            outputStream.write(tmp, 0, size);
        }

        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    public static byte[] decompressImage(byte[] data) {
        Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
        inflater.setInput(data);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

        try {
            while (!inflater.finished()) {
                int count = inflater.inflate(tmp);
                outputStream.write(tmp, 0, count);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

I upload the image like:

```
person.getAddress().setProfile_pic(ImageUtil.compressImage(file.getBytes()));
  personRepository.save(person);
```

And the image is saved to db successfully

The problem is image cannot be displayed.I did this when retrieving the data from db:

```
byte[] decomImage = ImageUtil.decompressImage(person.getAddress().getProfile_pic());
byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(decomImage);
String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
```

pojoprofile.setEncoded_image(base64Encoded);

I cannot retrieve the image and display it. I tried decompress the image and converted it into Base64 to display it in the thymleaf.

This is my controller class to upload image to database:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/EditProfile")
    public ModelAndView EditProfile(Model model, HttpSession httpSession){
        PersonPojo person=(PersonPojo) httpSession.getAttribute("loggedInPerson");
        Profile pojoprofile1=new Profile();
        pojoprofile1.setName(person.getName());
        pojoprofile1.setEmail(person.getEmail());
        pojoprofile1.setMobileNumber(person.getMobileNumber());
        if(person.getAddress()!=null&&person.getAddress().getAddressId()>0){
            pojoprofile1.setAddress1(person.getAddress().getAddress1());
            pojoprofile1.setAddress2(person.getAddress().getAddress2());
            pojoprofile1.setCity(person.getAddress().getCity());
            pojoprofile1.setState(person.getAddress().getState());
            pojoprofile1.setZipCode(person.getAddress().getZip_code());
            pojoprofile1.setProfile_pic(Base64.getEncoder().encode(person.getAddress().getProfile_pic()));

//            pojoprofile1.setProfile_pic(person.getAddress().getProfile_pic());
        }
        ModelAndView editprofile=new ModelAndView("EditProfile.html");
        editprofile.addObject("editprofile",pojoprofile1);
        return editprofile;
    }


@RequestMapping(value = "/updateProfile")
    public String updateProfile(@RequestParam("fileImage") MultipartFile file, @Valid @ModelAttribute("editprofile") Profile profile, Errors errors,
                                HttpSession httpSession) throws IOException {
if(errors.hasErrors()){
 return "EditProfile.html";
    }
   PersonPojo person=(PersonPojo) httpSession.getAttribute("loggedInPerson");
    person.setName(profile.getName());
    person.setEmail(profile.getEmail());
   person.setMobileNumber(profile.getMobileNumber());
   if(person.getAddress() == null || !(person.getAddress().getAddressId()>0)){
            person.setAddress(new AddressPoJO());
        }
        person.getAddress().setAddress1(profile.getAddress1());
        person.getAddress().setAddress2(profile.getAddress2());
        person.getAddress().setCity(profile.getCity());
        person.getAddress().setState(profile.getState());
        person.getAddress().setZip_code(profile.getZipCode());
        person.getAddress().setProfile_pic(ImageUtil.compressImage(file.getBytes()));
          personRepository.save(person);
        httpSession.setAttribute("loggedInPerson", person);
        return "redirect:/dashboard";
    }
```

Controller to display the content in Profile page:

```
@RequestMapping("/displayProfile")
public ModelAndView Myprofile(HttpSession httpSession) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Profile pojoprofile=new Profile();
    PersonPojo person=(PersonPojo) httpSession.getAttribute("loggedInPerson");
    pojoprofile.setName(person.getName());
    pojoprofile.setEmail(person.getEmail());
    pojoprofile.setMobileNumber(person.getMobileNumber());
    if(person.getAddress()!=null&&person.getAddress().getAddressId()>0){
        log.info("Inside the if"+new MyProfile().getClass().toString());
        pojoprofile.setAddress1(person.getAddress().getAddress1());
        pojoprofile.setAddress2(person.getAddress().getAddress2());
        pojoprofile.setCity(person.getAddress().getCity());
        pojoprofile.setState(person.getAddress().getState());
        pojoprofile.setZipCode(person.getAddress().getZip_code());
        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(ImageUtil.decompressImage(person.getAddress().getProfile_pic()));
        pojoprofile.setProfile_pic(encodeBase64);
    }else {
        pojoprofile.setAddress1(" Not available ");
        pojoprofile.setAddress2(" Not Available");
        pojoprofile.setZipCode(" Not Available");
        pojoprofile.setState(" Not Available");
        pojoprofile.setCity(" Not Available");
    }

    return new ModelAndView("profile.html").addObject("profile",pojoprofile);
}
```

Comment: can you show us the controller method responsible for retrieving the image?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/updateProfile")
    public String updateProfile(@RequestParam("fileImage") MultipartFile file, @Valid @ModelAttribute("editprofile") Profile profile, Errors errors,
                                HttpSession httpSession) throws IOException {
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            return "EditProfile.html";
        }
        PersonPojo person=(PersonPojo) httpSession.getAttribute("loggedInPerson");
        person.setName(profile.getName());
        person.setEmail(profile.getEmail());
        person.setMobileNumber(profile.getMobileNumber());

Comment: if(person.getAddress() == null || !(person.getAddress().getAddressId()>0)){
            person.setAddress(new AddressPoJO());
        }
        person.getAddress().setAddress1(profile.getAddress1());
        person.getAddress().setAddress2(profile.getAddress2());
        person.getAddress().setCity(profile.getCity());
        person.getAddress().setState(profile.getState());
        person.getAddress().setZip_code(profile.getZipCode());
        person.getAddress().setProfile_pic(Base64.getEncoder().encode(file.getBytes()));
          personRepository.save(person);
       }

Comment: please edit your post, don't add code to the comment section, which is hard to read. Post also the html containing the img tag that should display the image.

Comment: One thing I can see that your form has `th:object="${editprofile}"` but only the updateProfile method has a ModelAttribute matching that name. Myprofile doesn't have any ModelAttribute at all. I suggest that you add ModelAttribute(("editprofile") to that method as an argument and see what happens then.

Comment: I also suggest that you hit F12 in your browser and inspect what's going on under the Network tab. That should tell you more information about your requests.

Comment: Bro i actually have the object editprofile added already I edited the code please check. The logic is have another form exactly the same as I given above for only to show the data from the db which is called Profile.html it also had an edit button after clicking that edit we get a request  /EditProfile (I added the code) that request gives the editprofile.html from that HTML we get /updateprofile req when edited the form.

Comment: so what kind of response are you're getting? Your browser will try to load the image and if it fails it will display an http response status code that is different from 200 (OK).  This status can help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: When i tried to load the profile page I get all details except the image and in the Network tab it shows status failed(net::ERR_INVALID_URL) when hovering the status.

Comment: It show the error in the img tag in the attr src data:image/jpg;base64, and after this comma in devtools network tab it shows many numbers

Comment: And i more thing is that when we save the image to the db it showing like BLOB in blue color in that space. And I can see the image when I open that in viewer it showing only the bytes. Is there any error in storing the image. I mean in what format we can store the image and is there any mistake in comprising and decompresing the image

Comment: change this line pojoprofile.setProfile_pic(encodeBase64); to pojoprofile.setProfilePic(encodeBase64); This assumes that the image field is named profilePic and consequently the setter should be named setProfilePic. Not sure if this will resolve the issue though but you should use camel case when naming variables  in Spring. th:src should also be changed to `<img id="thumbnail" th:src="*{'data:image/jpg;base64,'+profilePic}" width="200" />`

Comment: But my profile and address entity i have given profile_pic as the field name for mapping and for the method name I use the lombok so the method for setting the profile_pic is suggested by it.

Comment: Bro i did exactly what you suggested. I changed my filed name as profilepic in both entity class and then lombok automatically suggested this setProfilePic() method still I cannot load the image in the browser.

Comment: do you have that project somewhere on github? I'd be willing to try it.

Comment: Sure bro here is the link: https://github.com/nikhilmathewfrancis98/School-Management-System.git

Comment: And one thing bro don't try to use the class AdminController under the package Controller because am still  building it. The Classes button under the Admin dashboard trigger the class AdminController.

Comment: Feel free to check the Schema.sql and data.sql under the resource folder for the schema and initial data

Comment: Use Becrypt generator online to Insert the pswd column for initial data of admin in the data.sql

Answer (score 0):

You should return a String representation of an image, rather than a byte array. So change your code to

```
 String encodeBase64 =   Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(person.getAddress().getProfilePic());

pojoprofile.setProfilePic(encodeBase64);
```

This means that Profile.profilePic is also a String. ( `person.getAddress().getProfilePic()`should return a valid byte array)

EDIT:
If you just want to make sure that this works without changing much of your code, I suggest adding a String field to Profile.java and setting that field with a hardcoded base64 image in your controller.

```
private String testImg; //in Profile.java

//in your controller
String picbase64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACEAAAAgCAYAAACcuBHKAAAACXBIWXMAABJ0AAASdAHeZh94AAAIgklEQVR42o1YCXAUxxXdMqZiynGAuJIyOI4hpIgxxAVxDkxSsZ2T4MRO4gOcA0MK4zikXDJHuCywJC6BAHEoWAgQAklcQpxCEAzCRoC4DwkBQhKX0bm72mtmd7Xb/fJ6Zo8RshBd9atnZn/3f/3+79+/14ZOmpRxCQvAHzJFPVub9beQaDuus2brzLhqQpoT39sCNOgNmobvbUpfyPZzPTAI6wDril1+iYLLEv/cA/x0rcRTSySeWGT2w9ZIvLcb2FQuYddk2/Gy/bz3BSEtA0Jh89muS6SUSDyZxgGTJWxTKEkSjxNAryVm/1By5PskAksFZh2SaPDJGCvyPqzYOgQQYWDfdYm+S6j4ocRj8yVeKwDmnQLWXQHyqoEttUA++/XXgNTTwBuFQM9Uaej3WggUVEqDCiuQDploD0BiJY3ZplFmSYzeK7GJxjZUhzHluI4Ru1wYkufEwA12PJ/vxO93uzHthB+51QJbCWz8AYmuSYodIOUzc75wFMg9bLRjImwFQOr7pEusuEhf1wqMLPai9+omPJxej66ULkvrYUurxyPLGvAQnx9Ob+DvzXiLenk1AqsvAwMyCGSiRNKROBDxZe6I+inqguLrigGJ/sulQXnaxSAG5Njx6IoGPL6qEb2zmtDjv40YvLEZfy1y4GsZjQa4b2Y2oSd/70a972bbMedswGBlSKYw4iW/HG1cE2UjxoSIIHTqwFNpEj3nCeRUAXPPBfDtNU3otboR31nXbEgvgng2pxmnvvBxkB8Jh1rwdRrvs7YJT69tRh+lQ1BPENR/6LrNNcCTiwW6z5G441Z2ZJtdZ2vLgsRHh/hxikDiceCTKyEas6P/+mbD90r6ZTdjcK4dZXdMAOGgjlCrjmmftxjgBhDc9zhmQGRcXwJSjCw6q9gVmFAkY1s3atsWZUFGWOgxT2II9/y2GwLDd7owkJQ/n+8wZNBGO4ZuduCkYkD6EfJrEAEdkiBESEdiqQv9aHgIdQfn2Y1+EAH/cJMD66+H8VKuxCMfC9xxyRj7MSai1GyuYBBNFZh7Ekg642f02/GzbU5D1EQvFThw6i4BgACUcbKAVr8BBARCVJhT5sKgPAde2KrEiWGU5wjk3cNeLD0vjVhbVia5aGnkIYMJK4jRhQKPkomNzA0j93vwcxr9zY4WvFjgJCtOnFYApE67XHkEQBSIAqW+STKy6LQbP9riwC93OPGLQifH85n96qsh9FoKjMgV8Tik2OK+kRjE7fTjbGANlUfsasEf9rRgOPs/7m3BmTozBlrpAoRpOBwHYIiKDwuQ5ec8eJGGX9ndYsz18nYnFlwI4LebmOYXSwTDMnYu2aKp2R0AupOFkTsllpYH8BoN/6nIhbf3u3CuXjNiIKizh46LdRrKbmsxID5Nx5bLmuEOFagGS3zOvOTB73a78Po+lwFmepmGsftMOw5NxPKSrTXChMrzX50r8Y9iYNFFP94sdmHMp24yYBpTLlAAyhs1Rr4bWefN2FDxENB1DMn1YEFZJGD5zYgZMrK23IvXi91MYC7MOOnDB9x9XZhJb0eCU5FgiwZHM0++x4hwDJEuvuTH6INukwH4zaBjLBy5oWHETg/97UZ+hcmOCGrw+nS8WeTB0K1uLDttAlH6EKbbMglk1AE3ks9qmPAp0C1Fot4rY4ekLRqUyke9maRe5QG16koA7xz0YOIRH2aU+jCJ/bgDXvyq0IuEY14M3+1BziUToNqebq+GN4q8+KDUg1f2ePFhiQ/JJzj2qBeTP2d/3IvxJR6kXtDxFx733+AB5wmIWL6wCUsufzlb4tlPJNZVhTCJxv7FCd77zIfxlHGceMoJL5LPaIahDeURluj/Fq+OtwhiMg1PP2nqjj3sw7sE/z7nSChV4uXignhhvcTgVeYWVUyI6BY1XSIx67BA12Qgs1JgzjkNKWd9TNuaIfMoH5/xYcF5DX8ujoOQ3BkOj45R/JZ4WsNsglS0pyjhmCS+z+b3RLppzdUwui8A3t9ryZrCkjFVO1/PZDJTIuEwt+m1oGF8ISlUNKpeAVhWQYP/82HDpXi8NLtJ834f5imdCxrmn9cNWXDBFAUoozKAmcc4/3SJg9WizdEeOztEJFcMzRL4FouY/Jowllf4DVlx2RQFIOuaH+8c0hgTPuqbWbPRpeHvBzSkV5g66eV65Nlv9Esu6SwFwuifAQxcKdDK+BP3nqLRA0z1h2rN1Kq26rZbrfSjn4YDZCbAjMeipSbAGNGRWxFlwo8ml44xBzVkRnQyDeEz3zMq/dh8oxUJJTQ2VWJ7ZXxrwnqAxYGYCmOZsGwzJOafkSi804qc6gCNB7GBAApvBzHhqB8ZjI8wt6BKTlXMHaOKNeTVBg3dnGrqUrKvB1BwO4T0i6xBWZ29mi8Nw8qOkLH6t21RY1Q9Qm0f4Dmm8K/MlkjjoVNUF8b2W0FsvRnEjtutXGEQ4+iSqcc0TKf8u0QFYgA7CXgLdbbcbDV099wNYQWr7x5zVZ0q0eQzXW7Ewv0KXRGpK2pbgGdY2nXhCiay0i66K3CwIcSeUhfCXsp2rlKtdOcXIRTzfRd7Zbi4XvWCOUaiG7NjX1bjVY72dWbHha7lrlHnBX6dbZbxP8iSSKV7iusESh1hHHeGcYJyvMV8Vt+OUor4u2JvWLZ5BfgJ885Nl6WsQ9zOfUt+WApeddgtLGUZP0cagfX0cuBtZr0k1gQZpHrNFbNP5vvf9gL9VprbUDEwuyR6O5OxOww6u3fE4sNSd8oIdw30Z+pRie+r6nmWMsTBMykfRfoZlESJZ1gcJ7OyvuWKW4w"
                + "yKzu4hdk6u4dai57INKhxSOy6ymvBSQYuE9CKMvO9yi6NIja6jHAnN69OL8QdXYof5JZtvQzjAW7mNjxAs17zo8wEw+atPCrq/d6/BKyuvV/7P1DzhMUXazLGAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
       
pojoprofile.setTestImg(picbase64);
```

You will have adjust profile.html as well to include this new field. (anyway I tested this and it's working as expected)

The fastest way to test your current code would be to call setProfilePic with a base64 hardcoded image

```
pojoprofile.setProfilePic( "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"
                + "yKzu4hdk6u4dai57INKhxSOy6ymvBSQYuE9CKMvO9yi6NIja6jHAnN69OL8QdXYof5JZtvQzjAW7mNjxAs17zo8wEw+atPCrq/d6/BKyuvV/7P1DzhMUXazLGAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" );
```

The Profile class should be changed as well, since we're now using a String instead of a byte[]

```
 class Profile {
  //base64 encoded image
  private String profilePic;//private byte[] profilePic;
  ....

 }
```

Comment: Then i may need to convert the multipart into byteArray or string value coz in the profile pojo the field to receive the profile is byte array so how can I encode it into String and save. Can u be more specific

Comment: @Nikhil Mathew, simply replace byte[] profilePic with String profilePic. Sure, you will have to adjust your code slightly to account for that change. Multipart is needed when uploading a file, otherwise it has no effect whatsoever. Anyway, there is a simply way to test my idea, i.e hardcoding a base64 picture , see my update.

Comment: Now what i must do is get the multipart and compress it into byte array and save it in the db. And when getting the image decompress it and convert it into string by encoding and display in the view am I correct.

Comment: Is it necessary to change the html code the img tag src attr

Comment: @Nikhil Mathew, you should only change your html if you add a new field (testImg) to your Profile class (for testing purposes). As for saving images in your db, can't you save them right away as a base64 string. It should be more efficient that way to retrieve the images as no conversion will be necessary.

Comment: Bro literally I did get you can you say what should be done step by step what all changes should be done with the existing code

Comment: @Nikhil Mathew, you really don't need to change anything other than what I've specified in my answer. The question was about not being able to display an image and I addressed that question alone. What other problems are you having? Have you tried implementing my solution?

Comment: Bro how to get the base64 string directly to check with the procedure you told

Comment: @Nikhil Mathew, updated to make it clear, hopefully.